# Javafx: Reading from an File and Spliting the result with .split method

Tags: java, split, filereader

I want to by reading the data of a file to split the results based on .split(",") in another words for this particular example i want to have 2 Indexes with each containing up to 5 informations which i would also like to acces with the .[0] and .[1] Method.

**the File with the Data.**

[image: Data]

**File Reading Method.**

```
public void fileReading(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("src/DateSpeicher/datenSpeicher.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
    String st; 
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println(st); 
    }
}
```

The method does work very greatly however, i wonder how can i split those two in two Indexes or String arrays which both can be accessed through respective indecies [0], [1]. For first data in the firm array - 655464 [0][0] for last in the second Array [1][4].

My approach: 
1. Making an ArrayList for every ,
2. Adding data till ","

**Issue**: eventho approach above works, you cant do such things as array1[0] - it gives an error, however the index method is crucial.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use Java 11+: `String[] arr = Files.readString​(Paths.get("src/DateSpeicher/datenSpeicher.txt")).split(",");` --- Basically, read *entire* text file into a string, *then* call `split(",")`. Do a web search if you need to read entire text file into memory on Java 10 or earlier.

Comment: `[]` is an operator, not a method and it only works for arrays. The list equivalent of `array[i]` is `list.get(i)` and in this case you do need lists, if you don't want to read the whole file multiple times, since you do not know the number of commata beforehand (that is unless you want to implement this basically reimplementing `ArrayList`'s logic yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/DateSpeicher/datenSpeicher.txt"); // Or:
Path path = Paths.get(new URL("/DateSpeicher/datenSpeicher.txt").toURI());
```

Either two Strings, and then handling them:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), Charset.defaultCharset());
String[] data = content.split(",\\R");
```

or a list of lists:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());

// Result:
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> newList = null;
boolean addNewList = true;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
    if (addNewList) {
        newList = new ArrayList<>();
        lists.add(newList);
        addNewList = false;
    }
    String line = lines.get(i);
    if (line.endsWith(",")) {
        line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
        addNewList = true;
    }
    newList.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'd keep the boolean; you could simply use `newList == null` as check and replace `addNewList = true;` with `newList = null;`; Furthermore both of your approaches read the whole file into the memory resulting in a memory consumption that is unnecessary high. `BufferedReader`+`while` seems the better approach to me compared to reading all the lines to a `List`...